# I am getting problem in array_merge in php?

Tags: php

I merge two arrays in php. Here is my code

```
$message = array_merge($message2, $message1);
echo json_encode($message);
```

here I get the data but here print "0" and "1"

```
{"username":"ji5vajng","gender":"MALE","profilepic":"http:\/\/li336-153.members.linode.com\/services\/uploads\/users\/thumbs\/000000000000000Sunset.jpg","status":"1","nickname":"laddu","0":{"username":"i3vnbtcz","gender":"MALE","profilepic":"http:\/\/li336-153.members.linode.com\/services\/uploads\/users\/thumbs\/7BB46853-D79D-5E17-807F-FD0666AF21BBi3vnbtcz-2011-06-13 11:04:26 +0000.png","status":"1","nickname":"Cool"},"1":{"username":"oq5mjbvb","gender":"male","profilepic":"http:\/\/li336-153.members.linode.com\/services\/uploads\/users\/thumbs\/7BB46853-D79D-5E17-807F-FD0666AF21BBoq5mjbvb-2011-06-13 05:45:57 +0000.png","status":"1","nickname":""},"2":{"username":"ejzxm2oz","gender":"MALE","profilepic":"http:\/\/li336-153.members.linode.com\/services\/uploads\/users\/thumbs\/A0000015BAB1CAreceived_0.jpg","status":"1","nickname":"laddu"}}
```

Comment: could you provide an example

Comment: 0 and 1 is your array index! You always can change those by itterate your array and rename/change your array's keys.

Comment: iam edit my code in above. please see above code

Comment: What's it *supposed* to print?

Comment: @narayana: Please add the contents of the two arrays you merge as well, e.g. as `print_r` output.

Comment: What is your problem? You just said you have one, not which one. Why is the json encoding a problem for you? Maybe you're just overlooking something? Please tell a bit more what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the normal behaviour of [`json_encode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), if the arrays have string keys that are not numeric, the numeric keys will be encoded as well.

```
$message1 = array('foo');
$message2 = array('key' => 'bar');

$message = array_merge($message2, $message1);
echo json_encode($message); # {"key":"bar","0":"foo"}
```

As you can see that's the object representation in json.

If all keys are numeric, they won't be part of the encoding:

```
$message1 = array('foo');
$message2 = array('bar');

$message = array_merge($message2, $message1);
echo json_encode($message); # ["bar","foo"]
```

This is the array representation in json.

Comment: Note: If all keys are numeric *and continuous and in order*, the JSON result will be an array. Try `array(1 => 'foo', 0 => 'bar')`...

Comment: @deceze: [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) takes care of that if the input arrays only have numeric keys. Your info is general a good hint but it is *not* relevant in the second code-example above as numeric keys will get re-numbered by `array_merge`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think theres something wrong with that result. Because your merged array should be...

```
(array(2)) '0' => array(username => 'foo',/* and so on */), 
           '1' => array(username => 'bar',/* and so on */)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just foreach it to get the value of the arrays and then put a json_encode on it?

```
foreach ($message as $value) { 
echo json_encode($value);
}
```

Comment: This will not result in a JSON array, just a bunch of JSON encoded values, not something you want. You can't parse this result by JavaScript anymore.

Comment: @KillZone, i'm showing how the question asker can reach to only the values, he wants to get to the values, then he needs to iterate over the array

Comment: No he wants to JSON encode an arary without showing numerical keys, which can be done as **hakre** showed. If you want to JSON encode *only* values, you have to do `json_encode(array_values($message))`, not looping and encoding the individual values.